# How to store the current state of the spring state machine in Redis Database?

Tags: spring-data-redis, spring-statemachine

I am trying to save the current state of the spring state machine into redis database. I create the Redis Config and all created API for sending the current state. Now, I want to persist this current state into Redis DB. What are the next steps here?

Comment: Please, add your question to what you did up to now in your code.

Comment: The next steps involve using the out-of-the-box State Machine Persister for Redis -> RedisStateMachineContextRepository - https://docs.spring.io/spring-statemachine/docs/1.1.1.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/statemachine/redis/RedisStateMachineContextRepository.html or if you are using SM 2.x -> https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-statemachine/2.1.x/api/org/springframework/statemachine/data/redis/RedisRepositoryStateMachinePersist.html